# How to transform list of dictionaries with jagged arrays to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Fairly new to Pandas.  I'm trying to get a json data set which looks like this

```
data = [
    {'id':1, 'colors':['red', 'blue']},
    {'id':2, 'colors':['red', 'blue', 'green']},
    {'id':3, 'colors':['orange', 'blue', 'orange']},
]
```

into a Pandas DataFrame which looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
                  'blue':[1,1,1],
                  'green':[0,1,0],
                  'orange':[0,0,2],
                  'red':[1,1,0]})
df
     blue  green  id  orange  red
0     1      0   1       0    1
1     1      1   2       0    1
2     1      0   3       2    0
```

Where the columns are 'id' and the unique colors and the rows are the ids and the count of each color in each original dictionary.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
df = [DataFrame(e) for e in data]
df = pd.concat(df)
df = df.pivot_table(index=['id'], columns=['colors'], aggfunc=len).fillna(0)
df

   blue  green  id  orange  red
0     1      0   1       0    1
1     1      1   2       0    1
2     1      0   3       2    0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ids = [item['id'] for item in data]
>>> col = [item['colors'] for item in data]

>>> ids = np.repeat(ids, list(map(len, col)))
>>> col = [a for item in col for a in item]

>>> df = DataFrame({'ids':ids, 'colors':col})
>>> df
   colors  id
0     red   1
1    blue   1
2     red   2
3    blue   2
4   green   2
5  orange   3
6    blue   3
7  orange   3
>>> df.groupby(['id', 'colors']).size().unstack().fillna(0)
colors  blue  green  orange  red
id                              
1          1      0       0    1
2          1      1       0    1
3          1      0       2    0
```

you may call `.reset_index` at the end, to have `id` as a column instead of index.

Answer (score 0):

I would first get the list of all unique colors using `set().union()` on the `colors` lists and then create the new dictionary using `collections.defaultdict`. Example -

```
In [10]: data = [
   ....:     {'id':1, 'colors':['red', 'blue']},
   ....:     {'id':2, 'colors':['red', 'blue', 'green']},
   ....:     {'id':3, 'colors':['orange', 'blue', 'orange']},
   ....: ]

In [11]:

In [11]: from collections import defaultdict

In [24]: colorlist = list(set().union(*colorlist))

In [25]: colorlist
Out[25]: ['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'green']

In [26]: newd = defaultdict(list)

In [30]: for x in data:
   ....:     xid = x['id']
   ....:     newd['id'].append(xid)
   ....:     for elem in colorlist:
   ....:         if elem in x['colors']:
   ....:             newd[elem].append(xid)
   ....:         else:
   ....:             newd[elem].append(0)
   ....:

In [31]: newd
Out[31]: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'id': [1, 2, 3], 'orange': [0, 0, 3], 'blue': [1, 2, 3], 'red': [1, 2, 0], 'green': [0, 2, 0]})

In [32]: df = pd.DataFrame(newd)

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
   blue  green  id  orange  red
0     1      0   1       0    1
1     2      2   2       0    2
2     3      0   3       3    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of list comprehension and dicts, for a faster alternative

```
In [2494]: pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(r['colors']+['id'], [1]*len(r['colors'])+[r['id']])) 
                        for r in data).fillna(0)
Out[2494]:
   blue  green  id  orange  red
0     1    0.0   1     0.0  1.0
1     1    1.0   2     0.0  1.0
2     1    0.0   3     1.0  0.0
```

---

Timings

```
In [2492]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(r['colors']+['id'], [1]*len(r['colors'])+[r['id']])) for r in data).fillna(0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 863 µs per loop

In [2493]: %timeit pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(e) for e in data]).pivot_table(index=['id'], columns=['colors'], aggfunc=len).fillna(0)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.79 ms per loop
```

---

Details

```
In [2495]: [dict(zip(r['colors']+['id'], [1]*len(r['colors'])+[r['id']])) for r in data]
Out[2495]:
[{'blue': 1, 'id': 1, 'red': 1},
 {'blue': 1, 'green': 1, 'id': 2, 'red': 1},
 {'blue': 1, 'id': 3, 'orange': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If using pandas 0.25 and up, explode is a convenience method

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(data)
        .assign(v=1)
        .explode('colors')
        .groupby(['id', 'colors']).sum()
        .unstack(1, fill_value=0)
        .reset_index(col_level=1)
      )

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```